# Age difference between Hiranyaksha and Hiranyakashipu

Tags: vishnu, puranas, bhagavata-purana, asuras

Varaha incarnation killed Hiranyakshya during beginning of current kalpa as per [this section of Bhagavata](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/3/13/).

> Text 17: Brahmā thought: While I have been **engaged in the process of**
> **creation**, the earth has been inundated by a deluge and has gone down
> into the depths of the ocean. What can we do who are engaged in this
> matter of creation? It is best to let the Almighty Lord direct us.

> Text 18: O sinless Vidura, all of a sudden, while Brahmā was engaged
> in thinking, a small form of a boar came out of his nostril. The
> measurement of the creature was not more than the upper portion of a
> thumb.

> Text 31: Lord Boar very easily took the earth on His tusks and
> got it out of the water. Thus He appeared very splendid. Then, His
> anger glowing like the Sudarśana wheel, **He immediately killed the**
> **demon [Hiraṇyākṣa]**, although he tried to fight with the Lord.

These verses from Bhagavata clearly says Varaha incarnation happened when Lord Brahma was busy in the process of creation during the current kalpa. Chapter 47 of Matsya Purana and Chapter 36 of Vayu Purana says Narasimha incarnation happened during 4th Treta Yuga of current Manvanatra. So Hiranyaksha was killed during beginning of current kalpa and
and Hiranyaksyapu was killed during 4th Treta Yuga of current Manvanatra. How can there be so much age difference between these brothers?

Comment: Read aage ka chapters. They’re twins. This seems to be a small verse error. At the beginning of the world Varaha came and lifted the earth and kept her on his tusks (though that verse says he went home, we know he didn’t go because in the very next chapters, he’s still holding the earth). Later in Vaivasvata when Hiranyaksha was born, Varaha was still holding the earth, like shesha holds it now. On being told by Varuna, Hiranya challenge Varaha and Varaha is doing Leela with him until devotees tell him that Hiranya is a tyrant. Then he’s killed. Then the Bhagavatham goes back to old Manvantara